# Fine tuning Code (C#), which way is better?

Tags: c#, if-statement

What is the better way of doing among the two below? please suggest any other better one if possible.

**First Way:**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
{
    sUri = sUri + "&fn=" + firstName + "&ln=" + lastName;
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
{
    sUri = sUri + "&fn=" + firstName + "&ln= ";
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
{
    sUri = sUri + "&fn= &ln=" + lastName;
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
{
    sUri = sUri + "&fn= &ln= ";
}
```

**Second Way:**

```
sUri = sUri + String.Format("&fn={0}&ln={1}", 
    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ? firstName : " "), 
    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) ? lastName : " "));
```

Comment: Perhaps de-compiling the generated code can give a clue

Comment: Check out the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`.  It doesn't deal with the string empty case, but you're replacing it with an empty string anyway.

Comment: You should also consider the possibility of using a StringBuilder

Comment: The second line of code works? That one gets my vote.

Comment: Define "Better", personally I think the 2nd one is "better" because it is a LOT less code to manage.

Comment: @EricJ. is pretty much right on the mark. Try to focus on the readability/maintainability of the code instead. Don't forget D.R.Y.

Comment: You should use `UrlEncode` on the values.

Comment: Measure what takes less time or memory, depending on your goals. If you can't measure the difference, don't worry about it, because no one else will either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the space, why not use the null-coalescing operator?

```
sUri = String.Format("{0}&fn={1}&ln={2}", sUri, firstName ?? " ", lastName ?? " ");
```

Comment: This one came little later. I am switching my acceptance to this one. Thank you very much Andrew.

Answer (score 10):

If you're going to append the query string parameters regardless of whether or not they're filled out you can simply do this

```
sUri = string.format("{0}&fn={1}&ln={2}", sUri, firstName, lastName);
```

(Note that this doesn't append spaces instead, because you don't need to do that in the case of a URI)

Comment: +1; this, so much. Unless the space for empty parameters is a necessary thing (which I highly doubt), this is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: +1, I was going to post this - but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I am glad. This looks much better. Thank you Brandon!

Answer (score 6):

I would go for explicit variables:

```
var sanitizedFirstName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ? " " : firstName;
var sanitizedLastName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) ? " " : lastName;

sUri = string.Format("{0}&fn={1}&ln={2}", sUri, sanitizedFirstName, sanitizedLastName);
```

Cleaner to read (imho)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should give you the same result:

```
sUri = sUri + String.Format("&fn={0}&ln={1}", firstName ?? " ", lastName ?? " ");
```

Comment: `??` only checks for null, not `IsEmpty`